# Recycler ItemDecoration - Dividers not being drawn, unsure why

Tags: android

I'm trying to display some dividers in my vertical recyclerview. When I use the default dividers provided:

```
 mRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext));
 mRecycler.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
  mRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
```

it works perfectly fine. However when I write my own custom class, nothing is displayed and I have no idea why.

```
public class PostDivider extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
    private Drawable mDivider;

    public PostDivider(Context context) {
        mDivider = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.divider_horizontal);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(@NonNull Canvas c, @NonNull RecyclerView parent, @NonNull RecyclerView.State state) {
        int left = parent.getPaddingLeft();
        int right = parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingRight();

        int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            View child = parent.getChildAt(i);

            RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

            int top = child.getBottom() + params.bottomMargin;
            int bottom = top + mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();

            mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
            mDivider.draw(c);
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the `R.drawable.divider_horizontal`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <size android:height="16dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/steelBlue" />
</shape>
```

Adding my custom dividers:

```
mRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext));
mRecycler.addItemDecoration(new PostDivider(mContext));
mRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Edit:  I swapped out `mContext` for getActivity() and it's not returning null. So i'm pretty lost to why it's not working

**Edit2: Seems to be a viewholder issue**

I simplified my entire viewholder to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:layout_margin="20dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/vh_buisnesspost_buisness_preview"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_circle_preview_border"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/vh_buisnesspost_post_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_below="@id/vh_buisnesspost_buisness_preview"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is where I'm confused: Why does it **ONLY** display the dividers when you add `android:layout_margin="20dp"` to the parent layout?!!!!

`android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"` doesn't work only `android:layout_margin="20dp"`WHY?!!!!!

Comment: One thing that stands out is that ItemDecoration is used as a template by the RecyclerView on a  per item basis.  As such, you should think of it as being responsible for dealing with a single row in your list as opposed to being responsible for all of the items in your list which is what you appear to be doing with your for loop.

Comment: Have you added data to the adapter?

Comment: Yes. Using the default divider class shows dividers

Comment: FWIW, I threw everything you've given here into a very basic test project, and the dividers are showing for me. Are you sure `steelBlue` is actually the color you're expecting?

Comment: I tested your PostDivider, but It's working

Comment: yes, your code snippet works in my case

Comment: Okay so I've tested in a new project and it works...https://i.imgur.com/9k6BwJT.png I cannot figure out why it's not working for my current project. Same code. I tried cleaning/rebuilding/invalidating caches and it doesn't work :/

Comment: The only difference between the working is that it's in a Activity and the non working is in a Nested Fragment, but that shouldn't make a difference right? I've also tried changing the divider to 100dp to see if it's being covered by anything...but that is not the case.

Comment: @MikeM. I found the issue. It was a viewholder issue. For some reason it doesn't draw dividers unless I add ```android:layout_margin="20dp"``` to the parent layout. https://pastebin.com/GTYqA8pX Adding only ```android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"``` doesn't work either. I don't know why I would need to add this attribute to the viewholder for it to work. Do you have an idea why? I thought making the divider height to 100dp would cover this issue, but apparently having a divider height that is too large also causes an issue and displays nothing.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure. I had tried earlier to get my test to fail by playing around with the margins and offsets, and it didn't happen. Also given that you're observing this only in a `Fragment`, I can't really wrap my head around it. Sorry.